# GWT + Acegi implementation

Tags: gwt, spring-security

I want to implement acegi security authorization in my GWT project.

I am not able to do it properly.

Can any one help thoroughly?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

[javacodegeeks](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/12/securing-gwt-apps-with-spring-security.html) have a nice tutorial with an example that can be of help. Though it is not complete for instance handling the logout/session timeout, it will give you a quick base where you can start off quickly.